# Ajax call no error but does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here my Ajax Call and it does not produce any error but it does not call the php file (I can see it in the network tab of my chrome, and when I call it in the javascript console, it's does return false as expected :

```
 function submitData() {
    $('#sortable2').sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            $.ajax({
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                url: './post_occupation_data.php'
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you call `submitData()` anywhere?

Comment: DO you get any error codes in the browser network tab?

Comment: Jon, Yes with a button or in the javascript console directly but does not work.

Comment: Ramanathan, no error and does not call the expected PHP file

Comment: Do you see this URL in the network tab "post_occupation_data.php".. or you don't ?

Comment: Ramanathan, I don't see it, that's my issue :(

Comment: to test , try to call another php file in the same level and without the ./file.php just the name like file.php

Comment: `url: './post_occupation_data.php'` is not hitting the correct url you need to do like   `url: '/post_occupation_data.php'` or  `url: 'post_occupation_data.php'`

Comment: anant  It worked one time but I can't make it work again

Comment: I don't know why too, but it's still does not work http://hastebin.com/iwexodoqox.coffee

Comment: may be  due to `update function`,like if updated successful then not going to call again or due to `return false` in last.

Comment: deleted the return false but does not work :(

Comment: Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but it sounds like you're expecting this ajax call to run when you call `submitData()` but this code won't run the ajax call until you actually sort something.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code and and check the if you are getting alert messages are not.. if 404 alert message please check your URL

```
  function submitData() {
    $('#sortable2').sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            $.ajax({
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                url: './post_occupation_data.php',
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                       alert(xhr.status);
                      alert(thrownError);
                      },
              success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                  }
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have no errors but it does not call the PHP file :(

Comment: does not php file means?

Comment: what do you meen by "it does not the PHP file"

Comment: use Ctrl+f5 to make sure your browser is using latest code and use success alert to check ajax code.

Comment: Yes I do this all time, you can check it here  
goldiman3.alwaysdata.net/Stack/occupation_data.php

Answer (score 0):

try to stringify the parameter like below

```
data: JSON.stringify(data)
```

Also add below parameters in your ajax call

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```